# Ancient Biblic Hebrew

Tags: hebrew

My question concerns the Biblical Hebrew.
In fact I'd like to know whether you know some online course (MOOC or otherwise) which might allow me to study the Biblical Hebrew.
I'm interested in ancient history of mankind so I would try to learn this ancient and fundamental language in our history.
I look forward to get your answer.
Best regards,
Antonio

Answer (score 0):

Google *Phoenician alphabet*. It's the original alphabet used in the bible

Comment: You may want to see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15422/501 before relying on this "fact".