# Is a Sfardi ש incorrect according to this Gemara?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, aleph-bet-letters, maseches-shabbos, safrus

In [Masechet Shabbat 104a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=104&format=pdf), it talks about the shapes of the letters, and meaning behind it. One thing it says is:

> ומאי טעמא **שיקרא** אחדא כרעיה קאי ו**אמת** מלבן לבוניה?
>
> And what is the reason that [letters of the word] שקר (falsehood) stand on one [leg], while [the letters of the word] אמת (truth) are like blocks? (Translation mine)

[image: שקר]

As you can see, each letter stands on one "leg". The ש tapers down to a point at the bottom.

For comparison, the word אמת:

[image: אמת]

But this is using Ashkenazi script. Let's look at a Sfardi ש now:

[image: Sfardi ש]

It stands on a full base, similar to the words in אמת! How can this be? It seems to invalidate the teaching here.

Comment: Interestingly, ש on Hebrew inscriptions up to about the 12th or 13th century CE appears always with a pointed bottom (according to the charts from Yardeni's "The Book of Hebrew Script").

Comment: It's midrash.... We don't get halakha from midrash.  And certainly not so tangential a midrash!

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman I didn't tag the question as halacha. I'm merely asking according to this *shita*.

Comment: @Scimonster he's saying it isn't really a shita to be asking according to.

Comment: FTR That is not Ashkenazi script but Ari script.

Comment: It's still on one leg: the lowest part of it is one piece, unlike the letters in _emes_. Just a wide leg.

Comment: @msh210 Interesting observation.

Comment: That can't be a proper Sefardi ש. There are no Tagim on it!

Comment: @DoubleAA Yeah, i know, but i couldn't find a picture of one with the Tagim. Other than that though, it matches the picture in my *tikun korim*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed, the Beit Yosef ([OC 36](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x101)) cites the Gemara you reference and claims that the ש should have a pointed base. The Peri Megadim ([EA end of 32](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x628)) is unsure if this is a necessary component of the letter. The Keset HaSofer ([5:2:ש](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41270&st=&pgnum=31)) implies it would be Kosher Bedieved, but one should be very careful to avoid a flat base. The Mishna Berura ([Mishnat Sofrim ש](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=126)) is not so sure though.

Comment: The same issue should apply to a Lamed, about whom the [Midrash says](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43333&st=&pgnum=6) it has no base but is standing on its leg like the Keruvim in the Mikdash were always standing.

Comment: The [Otiot R Akvia](http://torah.125mb.com/Midrash/Midrash.html) says Shin has no Raglayim and says it has "branches above but no roots below" which could be why it falls, not because it's pointy or flat at the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at a sefer torah written in the 'Sefaradi' style you will see that the Shin is not quite the same as the one you posted. Although it does have more of a base, you will see that it is still on a tilt. Only the bottom left corner reaches the bottom, the right side is raised. See this image for an example (from [here](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-4dGTA2BWFC0/UZ7-Aqr1yvI/AAAAAAAAAKo/5Hz8_c0YBhw/s1600/DSC_0024.JPG)):

[image: Scan of the beginning of a sefer Torah described above, including an example of the letter 'shin']